# how can we upload laravel project on cloud9?

Tags: laravel-5.3, cloud9-ide

can you please tell me how can we upload laravel project on c9.
I have made laravel project on localhost.
I know how to Install laravel on c9 but how can we upload existing laravel project on c9. Please help me **,Thanks**

Answer (score 2):

To upload files to Cloud9, either drag a local file directly from your desktop into the Cloud9 file tree, or use the `File` > `Upload Local Files` menu item (Source: [Cloud9 docs](https://docs.c9.io/docs/download-files)).

Since you want to upload a whole project, you may try dragging your folder or else zip your project first and then upload it.

*To actually setup Laravel, see [Getting Started with Laravel on Cloud9](https://community.c9.io/t/getting-started-with-laravel/1608) or [Laravel 5.3 Installation on Cloud9](https://community.c9.io/t/laravel-5-3-installation-on-cloud9/9038)*.

Comment: Is that it? Don't you have to also run a couple of commands to like set up composer and laravel and stuff like that?